# Google Chrome Cancels 4xx Client Error Response

Tags: json, apache-flex, google-chrome, actionscript, ruby-on-rails-3.1

Using Google Chrome I'm opening Flex4.5 Client that makes GET Http Request to Rails back end that renders back json response.

If the response is 4xx Client Error then Chrome Developer Tools network tab shows the request as canceled, and I can't access the response error message through the Fault content in Flex.

This happens only on chrome. It works fine for FF and IE or if I execute the query in the chrome browser.

Below are the request and response headers copied from Chrome Developer Tools

Thank you for your help

```
GET  (canceled)  application/json   Other
```

**Request Header**

```
GET url HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:3000
Connection: keep-alive
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 5.1) AppleWebKit/535.11 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/17.0.963.83 Safari/535.11
Accept: */*
Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate,sdch
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.8
Accept-Charset: ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.3
```

**Response Header**

HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found

```
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
X-Ua-Compatible: IE=Edge
Cache-Control: no-cache
X-Runtime: 0.500000
Content-Length: 30
Server: WEBrick/1.3.1 (Ruby/1.9.2/2011-07-09)
Date: Wed, 28 Mar 2012 21:53:40 GMT
Connection: Keep-Alive
```

Comment: This seems like it is the browser and not Flash Player itself, however, you might want to try disabling the "pepper" flash player that Chrome now seems to use by default. It has issues, and I'm only guessing that it could be the culprit. You can disable the pepper flash plugin (and leave the other Flash plugin(s) enabled) by going here:  chrome://plugins

Comment: Tried it, but still got  status (cancelled) and the response as (This request has no response data available)

Comment: This worked when I update to the latest chrome release Version 22.0.1229.94 m, and then disabled the pepper flash player, it seems working fine.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to get trace output from PPAPI content debugger Flash Player](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27791515/how-to-get-trace-output-from-ppapi-content-debugger-flash-player)